# Displaying a GoogleScript UiApp with the htmlService / html template

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a UiApp that creates some form elements that write data to a specific spreadsheet. Now I want to load the UiApp widgets into an htmlService template, and I'm not sure how to go about this.

My doGet function loads the base template, and the doGetApp builds the UiApp:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('base_template').evaluate();
}
function doGetApp() {
  // creates input forms for a spreadsheet (the following is just an example
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var tabPanel = app.createDecoratedTabPanel();
  var flowPanel1 = app.createFlowPanel();
  var flowPanel2 = app.createFlowPanel();

  tabPanel.add(flowPanel1, "Create New Projects");
  tabPanel.add(flowPanel2, "Edit Projects");
  app.add(tabPanel);

  // return app; // <<<< original doGet function returned the app

  // testing different ways of returning the UiApp 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(app); // this displays the text "HtmlOutput"
}
```

My base_html template is very simple right now:

```
<html >
<?!= getCSS("css_js"); ?>
  <body>
  <h1>Template Test</h1>
  <?!= doGetApp(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried a few variations on this, but the results are generally the same: Text output that appears to describe the object, as opposed to displaying the UiApp. (the getCSS function works fine)

The goal is to be able to easily load some of my own css / js as well as the UiApp in order to easily style the forms / resulting content. I'm pretty new to this, so it is entirely possible that I'm approaching this the wrong way. Appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

-greg

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use the *[html or body tags](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices)*.

Answer (score 2):

For now,  you either use html service or uiapp - you cannot combine the two

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you know if it's possible to use the UiApp, but still import my own css or javascript to more easily control the UiApp display?

Comment: OK, this might be a hack, but... what if, I create one app, which is based in html service, and use that to embed the second app, which is based in UiApp? I can embed the UiApp in a googlesite, So I would think it should be possible to chain them together this way, less than ideal...

Comment: Sigh, I thought I was close to the answer there, but it turns out I'd need to use a proxy server because the iframe won't display the UiApp unless it is within a google Site... which I wanted to avoid...